# How to check if a variable is an object with no own properties defined by the developer?

Tags: javascript, string, object, types, hasownproperty

In my code there is a variable that sometimes is one of:

- a number,
- a boolean,
- a string,
- a regular expression,
- a date,
- an object with 0 or more *"own"* properties.

I want to check if that variable is an *"elementary object"*. I define *"elementary object"* as being either:

- a number,
- a boolean,
- a string,
- a regular expression,
- a date,

or, with other words, an object with no *"own"* properties defined by the developer.

I used the condition `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length === 0` but strings (which, according to the definition above, are *"elementary objects"*) have *"own"* properties for each character and for the length of the string. For example, if I run `Object.getOwnPropertyNames("test")` 
in both Chrome (46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 15.10) DevTools console and Firefox 42 on Ubuntu 15.10, it prints `["0", "1", "2", "3", "length"]` (in Chrome) and `[ "length", "0", "1", "2", "3" ]` (in Firefox).

So, what is the most readable way to check if a variable is an *"elementary object"* as a term explained above? I am not interested in performance, but in readability and easiness of debugging.

Thank you very much! `:-)`

**Update:**

I started using this function, although I hope somebody will give me a solution that is compatible with new types without any change.

```
function isElementaryValue(x) {
    return typeof x === "number" ||
        typeof x === "boolean" ||
        typeof x === "string" ||
        x instanceof RegExp ||
        x instanceof Date;
}
```

Comment: Numbers, booleans and strings are usually no objects?

Comment: You could try `Object.keys` instead, which only considers enumerable properties

Comment: @Bergi, in both Firefox and Chrome, `Object.keys("test")` returns `["0", "1", "2", "3"]` so it is not useful for me. To be useful for me it should return an empty array.

Comment: Oh, interesting, in ES5 `Object.keys` still threw on primitives… I thought you would test this only on objects, and filter numbers/booleans/strings before.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write a quite bespoke function for that, because those types do not have much in common:

```
function isElementary (arg) {
  return arg === null
    || arg === undefined 
    || (typeof arg !== 'object' && typeof arg !== 'function') 
    || arg instanceof RegExp 
    || arg instanceof Date;
}
```